# How to return a Promise with argument which returned to then()?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

It's a little complicated. Let show the code:

```
requestAccessToken().then(function(requestResult) { // this is the first then()
    if(requestResult.ok == 1) {
        return document;
    }
}).then(function(document) { // this is the second then()
    return db.update(updateArgu); // here, db.update will return a promise obj
}).then(function(result) { // this is the last then()
    console.log('update ok');
    console.log(result);
});
```

Since the `db.update(updateArgu)` will return a promise object, it can add a `.then()` method like `db.update().then()`.

But I want to keep the main chain like `requestAccessToken().then().then()` so I returned the `db.update()` in the second `then()`. The output is:

```
app-0 update ok
app-0 undefined
```

The `db.update` code is:

```
exports.update = function(arguments) {
    var name = arguments.name;
    var selector = (arguments.selector) ? arguments.selector : {};
    var document = (arguments.document) ? arguments.document : {};
    var options = (arguments.options) ? arguments.options : {};
    return Promise(resolve, reject) {
        MongoClient.connect(DBURL, function(err, db) {
            if(err) throw err;
            db.collection(name).update(selector, document, options, function(err, result) {
                db.close();
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

You can see it has `resolve(result)`, how can I transfer it to the last `then()`?

Comment: It *is* transfered to the last `then` callback, otherwise that wouldn't have been called at all. It's just that `result` is `undefined`. Isn't it? What did you expect the Collection `update` method to return?

Comment: put a console.log inside your MongoClient callback and see what result is.  Also you want to return a 'new Promise'

Comment: @Bergi yes, the last `then()` be called, but no `result`

Comment: `return Promise()` should be `return new Promise()`.

Comment: @BrickYang: I was meaning that `result` is undefined in the `db.update` callback already. Did you check back there? This doesn't seem to be a promise problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, it's the problem. and it should be `return new Promise(function(){});`. It woks now. Thanks

Comment: @Bergi the `collection.update` should return a result which is `{ result: { ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 },...` My mistake is write a wrong `Promise`. It works now. Thanks

Comment: What promise library are you using that didn't either throw an exception or returned the promise object for this usage without `new`?

Comment: @BrickYang: Hm, the native `Promise` constructor should have thrown an exception if not called with `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make my comment into an answer.

Where you do:

```
return Promise(resolve, reject) {
   ...
}
```

it should be:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    ...
});
```